# Android make a edit info fragment

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm making an Android app. I have to make a fragment where (for example) the user can see his info, like his name, email, birthdate, etc. I want to allow the user to edit this info, but i don't know which approach is better. I thought to put all the infos in some editTexts with setEditable = false and make a button **EDIT** that when the user click on it I set the visibility of this button to GONE and make the visibility of the hidden button **UPDATE** to VISIBLE and the editTexts to setEditable = true. When the user click on **UPDATE** if is all correct i send the updated infos to the backend and I set again the visibility of **UPDATE** button to  GONE and the visibility of button **EDIT** to  VISIBLE and all the editTexts to setEditable = false.
Is it a good solution or i can do it better?

Comment: This is more of a user interface question than a programming question. You might try posting at https://ux.stackexchange.com/ but make sure you read their FAQ about what's on-topic.

Comment: i didn't know the existance of this site.. but now i have to wait 50 min to post the asnwer

Comment: pls someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best approach would be to to display user profile in the fragment and then provide a button for the user to click on to Edit. On button click you can launch a new activity to allow editing - this is the approach i generally use. It is less complicated in the beginning. On the other hand, it would be nice to implement both and then use A/B testing to figure out what works best for your users, in your context. This is more a UI/UX issue rather than a programming one... all the best.